# Программа не видит сетевой интерфейс

Tags: golang

Есть [пакет](https://github.com/basilfx/go-wireless)  для работы с вифи. Для создания клиента в этом пакете используется функция wireless.NewClient(), которая принимает в качестве агрумента имя интерфейса вифи. У меня это wlp3s0. Но я получаю ошибку при попытке что то сделть с помощью клиента, который принимает wlp3s0 как аргумент.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Причина этой ошибки нашлась быстро с помощью вывода интерфейсов

```
iface := wireless.Interfaces()
log.Println(iface)
```

А именно  в iface не содержит нужного мне wlp3s0 получается что функция Interfaces в этом пакете не работает как нужно и возвращает не все интерфесы системы. Но если смотреть интерфесы с помощью

```
iface, _:= net.Interfaces()
```

То wlp3s0 находит.
Почему же пакет wireless не видит нужного интерфейса и как исправить?

Мне необходимо просканировать вифи сети поблизости...Может есть альтернативный метод/пакет это сделать?
Пробовал запускать программу с sudo но результат тот же

Comment: Требования про WPA Supplicant были соблюдены?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в этом моменте я не понял что от меня требуется

Comment: @DanielProtopopov `ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel` делал

Comment: если ошибку не игнорировать, а обрабатывать, то можно будет понять что конкретно пишет

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в вопросе была опечатка. Там wireless.Interfaces() не возвращает ошибок